# Why am I having an error connecting javascript to simple html?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

I am attempting to connect [szimek's signature pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) to my simple html document. I am testing out the program but cannot get it working in my atom text editor:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"
    </script>

  </head>
  <h1>
  Please Sign
</h1>
<div class="wrapper">

  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

// Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});
```

I have put the same code into js fiddle, and the project works fine. I am connecting through a CDN, and the error I am getting in my own project's inspection is:

```
script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: SignaturePad is not defined
    at script.js:1
```

Comment: Did you try putting the CDN link inside the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"
</script>
```

Does not load the script `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js` it is a script containing the string `"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script tag is wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      JS CODE
</script>
```

This tag is used to include JS code in your page.  The line `JS CODE` is intended to *be* the code.  If you want to pull in an external script, the above code is not the right way to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js">
</script>
```

The key here is your script tag needs to specify the location where your browser can find the script.  It does this using the `src` attribute on the `script` tag.  As you currently have it, you have some code containing a single string, which doesn't do much.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"
</script>
```

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
```